# Can't set the cookie to browser in mern app

Tags: reactjs, express, redux, cookies, jwt

I am trying set a two tokens when a user try to login. One of them is refresh_token and other one is access_token. As I am using redux in the frontend so my access_token will be set to redux state whereas my refresh_token should be stored in browser cookie. Everything working fine except my cookie. Here is my code:

server.js:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const corsOption = require('./config/corsOption')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3500
const authHandler = require('./routes/authRoutes')


app.use(cookieParser(process.env.COOKIE_SECRET))
app.use(
    cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    }))
app.use(express.json())


app.use('/',authHandler)

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.status(200).json({ 'message': 'Server responding successfully.'})
})

app.all("*",(req,res) => {
    res.status(404).json({'message':'Not found!'})
})

app.listen(PORT , ()=>{
    console.log(`Server is running in port ${PORT}`)
})
```

login controller:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const dbConnections = require('../config/dbConnect')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')



const loginUser = async(req,res) =>{
    try{
        const database = await dbConnections()
        const collection = database.collection('users')

        const { email , password } = req.body

        if(!email || !password){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ "message": "Failed. No empty field allowed!" })
        }

        if(!/^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$/.test(email)){
            return res
            .status(404)
            .json({ "message": "Invalid email format!" })
        }
        const query = { email : email }
        const user = await collection.findOne(query)

        if(!user){
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
                "message":"No user found with this email. Please signup."
            })
        }

        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password,user.password)

        if(!match) {
            return res
            .status(400)
            .json({
                "message":"Invalid password!"
            })
        }

        const refresh_token = jwt.sign({ 
                email:email,
                role: user.role
            },
            process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
            {expiresIn: '2h'}
        )

        const access_token = jwt.sign({ 
                email:email,
                role: user.role
            },
            process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN,
            {expiresIn: '15m'}
        )


        res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, {
            path: "/",
            sameSite: "none",
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: true,
        })

        res
        .status(200)
        .json({ 
            "access_token": access_token,
            "message": "Login successfully." 
        })

    }catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Frontend:

store.js:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import authSlice from "../feature/auth/authSlice"
import { apiSlice } from "./api/apiSlice"

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        auth : authSlice,
        [apiSlice.reducerPath] : apiSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) => getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware)
})
```

apislice.js:

```
import { createApi , fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"


export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3500'
    }),
    credentials: 'include',
    tagTypes: [],
    endpoints: builder => ({})
})
```

authApiSlice.js

```
import { apiSlice } from "../../app/api/apiSlice";


export const authApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
    endpoints: builder =>({

        login: builder.mutation({
            query: ( credentials ) =>({
                url   : '/user/login',
                method: 'post',
                body  : credentials,
            })
        }),

    })
}) 

export const {
    useLoginMutation,
} = authApiSlice
```

authSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"

const initialState = {
    user : {},
}

export const authSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'auth',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        logIn: (state,action) =>{
            state.user = action.payload
        },
        signUp: (credentials) =>{
            
        },
        logOut: () =>{

        }
    }
})


export const { logIn , logOut , signUp} = authSlice.actions
export default authSlice.reducer
```

I tried different browser locally. But result seems to be same in all.
I have checked in network tab. I found my cookie there but not in application tab.

Answer (score 0):

I hope needed `maxAge` attribute like this

```js
res.cookie('refresh_token', refresh_token, {
    path: "/",
    sameSite: "none",
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false, 
    maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 2 hr
});
```

Comment: I have tried using both maxAge and expiresIn but the situtation is always same. In fact i found my cookie in the network tab under Set-Cookie section but for unknown reason my cookie is not being set to cookie storage. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That is you can use set cookies on you browser

```
  res
    .cookie("acces aaaaaaa", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "strict",
      expires: expirationDate,
    })
    .send({ massage: "success" });
```

Use `.cookie` to send cookies then that will be save on browser applications tab. And after `.send` or `.json` you will send your Expected values. And also when you send or receive data API call like this

```
baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:4000",
    prepareHeaders(headers) {
      return headers;
    },
    credentials: "include"
  }),
```

or

```
        query: () => {
          return { url: `/getuser`, credentials: "include" };
        },
```

Use credentials: "include" every time when you get, post, patch or delete. I hope it will help and you understand what I trying to say.